# Trying to transform the structure of this hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this hash:

```
{
  :items => {
    :"cust.category" => "Jackets,Belts & Buttons",
    :"items.receive_dt" => "2 years",
    :"prdcts.brand" => "Armani"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to change this hash such that it becomes -->

```
{
  :items => ["cust.category=Jackets,Belts & Buttons", 
    "items.receive_dt=2 years", 
    "prdcts.brand=Armani"]
}
```

I've tried a few things and was not able to get it right

Comment: "[I] was not able to get it right" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 5):

```
h = {
  :items=>{
     :"cust.category"=>"Jackets,Belts & Buttons",
     :"items.receive_dt"=>"2 years",
     :"prdcts.brand"=>"Armani"
}
```

```
h.transform_values { |g| g.map { |a| a.join('=') } }
  #=> {:items=>["cust.category=Jackets,Belts & Buttons",
  #             "items.receive_dt=2 years",
  #             "prdcts.brand=Armani"]
  #   }
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Comment: This creates a copy, so it's worth noting to alter the original structure use `transform_values!`.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few different ways to accomplish this, here's one way using `to_a` on your hash:

Your hash would look like:

```rb
hash = {
  :items => {
    :"cust.category" => "Jackets,Belts & Buttons",
    :"items.receive_dt" => "2 years",
    :"prdcts.brand" => "Armani"
  }
}
```

You could then alter the hash by turning `hash[:items]` into an array and then using `map` to convert the result into an single array of joined strings:

```rb
hash[:items] = hash[:items].to_a.map { |a| a.join('=') }
```

The final `hash` would then look like:

```rb
{
  :items => [
    "cust.category=Jackets,Belts & Buttons",
    "items.receive_dt=2 years",
    "prdcts.brand=Armani"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.7, [Hash#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Hash.html#method-i-to_h)

```rb
hash = {
  :items => {
    :"cust.category" => "Jackets,Belts & Buttons",
    :"items.receive_dt" => "2 years",
    :"prdcts.brand" => "Armani"
  }
}

pp hash.to_h { |k, v| [k, v.map { |e| e.join('=') }] }
```

Output

```
{:items=>
  ["cust.category=Jackets,Belts & Buttons",
   "items.receive_dt=2 years",
   "prdcts.brand=Armani"]
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the change to `Hash#to_h` that permitted it to have a block. A detail: it appears that came was made in v2.6.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I believe all methods are permitted to have a block.  No error was raised when providing a block to `Hash#to_h` in Ruby 2.1.10 for example.  In order to not "permit" a block one would need to write the code to raise an error if a block is given.  Usually, we just ignore blocks if we don't want to do anything with them.  Different than "not permitted".  Perhaps "ignored" is a better description.

Comment: @vgoff, good point from someone I've not heard from in awhile: `"abc".upcase { "Let's see if this block is problematic" }
 => "ABC"`.